# Unable to view Target framework 461 in VS while publishing the uipath custom created code

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, uipath

Unable to view Target Framework net461 option when I publish the C# package(uipath custom code), instead it is `net6.0-windows`, can someone help me to publish it on 461 version,

[image: Expected version in uipath documentation]

[image: Target framework in my VS]
I have installed dot net 4.6.1 sdk file, still the option is not showing while publishing.

Comment: i think net6.0 and framework 4.xx have totally different project file structures. try to create an empty project for framework and empty project for net6  - you will see differences.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the framework when you create the project
[From UiPath guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auuGl.png)

https://docs.uipath.com/developer/other/latest/developer-guide/creating-activities-with-code

Suggest you create a new Class Library project, specify the 4.6.1 framework and copy your project files into your new project.